# Laravel/Vue.js issues

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I need help with my code please. I can't figure it out. I'm getting a "TypeError: this.$http is undefined" and it's driving me insane. I trace it to $http, but I have no idea how to fix it. I've just finished my Laravel course, but Vue.js is new to me. Here's is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                          <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" v-model="content"></textarea>
                          <br>
                          <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" :disabled="not_working" @click="create_post()">
                                Create a post
                          </button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
        mounted() {

        },
        data() {
              return {
                    content: '',
                    not_working: true
              }
        },
        methods: {
              create_post() {
                    this.$http.post('/create/post', { content:          this.content })
                        .then((resp) => {
                              this.content = ''
                              noty({
                                      type: 'success',
                                      layout: 'bottomLeft',
                                      text: 'Your post has been   published !'
                              })
                              console.log(resp)
                        })
              }
        },
        watch: {
              content() {
                    if(this.content.length > 0)
                          this.not_working = false
                    else
                          this.not_working = true
              }
        }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you install vue-resource via npm install vue-resource ?

Comment: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource more details on this page..

Comment: +1 for what @ankitpatel said. Watch this laracast video about laravel assets - [Laravel Mix in a Nutshell](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-4/episodes/3) and then take a look and [Laravel Mix documentation](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-4/episodes/3)

Comment: No I didn't Install that package. I'm using php storm and it usually prompts me to install a package when needed I guess one must have slipped

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a error in submitting the post request.
you need to learn about axios.
Try this example.

```
axios.post('/create/post', this.content).then((response) => {
            // do something
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install axios --save
```

Add Axios to your Vue.js project, you have to import it:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      errors: []
    }
  },

  created() {
   let payload={
content:this.content
 }
    axios.post('/create/post',payload)
    .then(response => {
      this.posts = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```